# Why do we not order the scaled features inline with eigen vectors in PCA?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pca

The code below is a typical example of the PCA process that I see on web.

In most cases the eigen vectors and values are re-ordered, but the features data (X_meaned) are not. Can someone explain why that is NOT applying the wrong vectors to the data in the dot.product (step-6)?

I have added a 'Step_NEW' why is that unnecessary?

## https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/principal-component-analysis

```
import numpy as np
 
def PCA(X , num_components):
     
    #Step-1
    X_meaned = X - np.mean(X , axis = 0)
     
    #Step-2
    cov_mat = np.cov(X_meaned , rowvar = False)
     
    #Step-3
    eigen_values , eigen_vectors = np.linalg.eigh(cov_mat)
     
    #Step-4
    sorted_index = np.argsort(eigen_values)[::-1]
    sorted_eigenvalue = eigen_values[sorted_index]
    sorted_eigenvectors = eigen_vectors[:,sorted_index]

    #Step-NEW 
    X_meaned= X_meaned[sorted_index]
     
    #Step-5
    eigenvector_subset = sorted_eigenvectors[:,0:num_components]
     
    #Step-6
    X_reduced = np.dot(eigenvector_subset.transpose() , X_meaned.transpose() ).transpose()
     
    return X_reduced
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this is more a math question than a python question.

But I feel that you are confusing sorting the components of the data, and sorting vectors.
When you sort eigenvectors, you don't sort their components.

Note that I am not 100% sure that this is your misunderstanding. Only that there is a misunderstanding. Since line

`X_meaned= X_meaned[sorted_index]`

doesn't make any sense. Nothing says that you would not have a "index out of bound" from this. `sorted_index` are indices between 0 and N-1, where N is the number of dimensions of your eigenspace (most of the time, unless either you choose to restrain the PCA, or you have a 100% correlation between some axis, which never happens in real life, so most of the time, N is also the dimension of your X vectors. That is the dimension of `X[i]` or `X_meaned[i]`.
There is no reason why that N should also be the size of `X` (that is, not the dimension of your data, but the number of data).

Let's use a simpler example, using basic 2D-geometry.

Let say that your are trying to do a PCA on a set of points

```
X=np.array([
   [1.4,15],
   [2.1,20],
   [-3, -31],
   [-0.5, -4]
  ])
```

## Step 1

is to mean this. It happens that mean is already `[0,0]` (because I am lazy, so I've chosen an example where it is, and because this is obviously not the step you are misunderstanding). So `X_meaned` is the same as `X`.

## Step 2

is to compute covariance matrix
The diagonal elements are just the variance of each components.
So

```
Var(X₁) = (1.4² + 2.1² + (-3)² + (-0.5)²)/3 = 5.2066667
Var(X₂) = (15² + 20² + (-31)² + (-4)²)/3 = 534
```

And the non diagonal elements (here, there is just one, since covariance matrix is symmetric, and any way, with 2 dimensions, there is only one possible covariance

```
Cov(X₁,X₂) = (1.4*15 + 2.1*20 + (-3)*(-31) + (-0.5)*(-4))/3 = 52.6666667
```

Hence the covariance matrix

```
[[5.20666667,    52.6666667],
 [52.6666667,    534       ]]
```

Your code obviously gives the same result

```
np.cov(X, rowvar=False)
#array([[5.20666667, 52.6666667],
#       [52.6666667, 534       ]])
```

This alone gives a first hint about the PCA result: covariance between the two variables is almost identical to geometrical mean of variances (52.6667 ≈ √5.206667*534). Which means that they are highly correlated.

## Step 3

is to diagonalize this. That is to find another base (instead of the traditionnal i,j base, that is (1,0),(0,1) base) in which that covariance matrix is diagonal.

We could do this by hand, as you have probably learned at school (compute characteristic polynomial to find 2 eigenvalues, and then solve equations CovX=λX to find eigenspaces).

But well, long story short, we find 2 eigenvalues
λ₁ = 1.22×10⁻² and λ₂=539.2
And two associated vectors
u₁ = [0.995, -0.098] and u₂=[0.098, 0.995]

So, here it is important to understand what it means. It means that if you use this basis instead of the canonical one, to represent your 4 data in `X`, then, the coordinates of those 4 points, which were obviously correlated in canonical basic (y is very similar to x with a factor 10), are not in the new basis.

Your 4 points, in the new coordinates system are now

```
array([[ -0.07905101,  15.06498427],
       [  0.12680531,  20.10954799],
       [  0.05722047, -31.14477044],
       [ -0.10497477,  -4.02976182]])
```

For example, the third one, whose coordinates were (-3.-31) in the canonical system (understand that this means that it is -3*(1,0) + -31*(0,1)), has coordinates (0.057, -31.145) in the new system. That is that point is also 0.057*u₁ -31.145*u₂ (and you can easily check that, indeed, is still (-3,-31)).

This coordinates system is better because, firstly, in this coordinates system, coordinates are independent. You can easily check that points

```
array([[ -0.07905101,  15.06498427],
       [  0.12680531,  20.10954799],
       [  0.05722047, -31.14477044],
       [ -0.10497477,  -4.02976182]])
```

have 0 covariance.

And also because it separates the main axis, the one along which most of the variation occurs, from the less important one, the one along which only small variation around the main tendancies occur.

In our example, main axis is the one for which y=10x (as we have already noticed, our data mainly follow this rule).
And the least important axis is small variation to that rule, that is an axis that quantity how different are nevertheless y and 10x.

To know which of our new axis u₁, u₂ (even if, in our case, it is obvious by watching it), you can rely on the eigenvalues.

## Step 4

This is why it is customary (not compulsory) to sort the vector of the basis by their eigenvalue.

After all, what we are doing here, is just choosing axis to represent our data. The order of those axis are arbitrary (exactly like naming one axis `x` and the other `y` in the canonical basis was arbitrary. You could have chosen to call `x` what I've called `y` and `y` what I've called `x`. It is just a naming choice). So, since we can choose what ever order we want, there is no reason to stick to order u₁, u₂, and we could choose to use vectors u₂,u₁ for our new coordinates system if we want. The habit in PCA is to use vectors with highest eigenvalues first.

So, here, since eigenvalue associated with u₂ is λ₂=539, which is way bigger than eigenvalue associated with u₁, λ₁=0.0122, let's use (u₂,u₁) instead of (u₁,u₂) for our basis. Therefore our coordinates of our 4 points are now

```
array([[ 15.06498427,  -0.07905101],
       [ 20.10954799,   0.12680531],
       [-31.14477044,   0.05722047],
       [ -4.02976182,  -0.10497477]])
```

Exactly the same as before, but with swapped coordinates.

When I say that it is just an habit, that it is just customary, understand that there are more than aesthetical reason tho. That means that if you want to represent your data with less values (for example for a compression purpose), you can choose the keep only the first M columns. In my example, representing all our data along a single axis would no introduce much error, since almost all the information is on the first axis, now that I sorted my axis so that the main one is the first one.

With another example in dimension 100, you could choose to keep only the 10 main axis, which, if you have sorted your axis by eigenvalues is easily done by dropping all but the 1st 10 columns.

Note that the computation of coordinates in the new system is Step 5.
And note that we did it twice (once without doing step 4, and once with step 4), and that resulted in sorting the columns of our data (here, since we are in dimension 2, just swapping them), not in sorting the rows, that is the data themselves.

Sorting the rows have absolutely no meaning. There is never and there was never any particular order in those rows. And if the application have one (that is if you have a reason other than random to consider that [1.4, 15] should be the first of our 4 points), then, there is no reason why that order should change because we changed our coordinates system. No more than deciding to call `y` what we called `x` and `x` what we called `y` should change the order of the points.

Your "Step-New" nevertheless does that: it changes, for no reason, the order of the points themselves.

Note that the columns (the coordinates of the points in the new system) should change if you change the order of the vectors in the new basis. But that is done naturally simply by the fact that you performed step-4 before step-5 (in other words, the projection in the new basis is done only after you have chosen the new basis vectors order)

And to go back on my first remark: in my example, this step-New would not harm a lot (it would just swap the 1st and 2nd of our 4 examples data, which, after all, doesn't change anything, neither in good nor in bad, unless your application need your data in order, in which case you scrambled them. For example, if you want to plot them with predifined color to do some gating).

But if I have had 4 points in a 6 dimension space, then, your step-new would have resulted into an index error, when you try to reposition `X[4]` and `X[5]` that do not exist.

Sorry for the very long explanation. I got myself carried out. But I felt that the real problem here was the understanding of what you are doing when you are doing a PCA.